# On scroll to section, add active class to div with corresponding anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sticky navigation that links to anchors with unique id's on a page. I must include the full link as this nav will be on other pages. I would like for when I scroll to a section, that the corresponding nav link will have the class "active" added. Thank you for any help received
I've included the code below and the script is something I have been working with but not quite there but any suggestions are welcome. Thanks again!

```js
const changeNav = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if(entry.isIntersecting && entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.85) {
            document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
            // get id of the intersecting section
            const id = entry.target.getAttribute('id');
            // find matching link & add appropriate class
            const newLink = document.querySelector(`[href="#${id}"]`).classList.add('active');
        }
    });
}

const options = {
    threshold: 0.85
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(changeNav, options);

// target the elements to be observed
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
sections.forEach((section) => {
    observer.observe(section);
});
```

```css
nav {
position: sticky;
top: 0px;
}

.wrapper {

    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}


element.style {
}
.nav-link.active {
    color: #aa812d;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="nav-container">
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.somedomain.com#welcome" onclick="navFunction()">
              WELCOME
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.somedomain.com#destination" onclick="navFunction()">
              DESTINATION
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.somedomain.com#hotel" onclick="navFunction()">
              HOTEL
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.somedomain.com#agenda" onclick="navFunction()">
              AGENDA
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.somedomain.com#program" onclick="navFunction()">
              PROGRAM
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.somedomain.com#winners" onclick="navFunction()">
              WINNERS
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.somedomain.com#travel" onclick="navFunction()">
              TRAVEL
            </a>
          </li>


        </ul>
       
    </nav>
    
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  <section id="welcome" class="section">
  <h2>Welcome</h2>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    <br/><br/>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </section>
    <section id="destination" class="section">
  <h2>Destination</h2>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    <br/><br/>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </section>
      <section id="hotel" class="section">
  <h2>Hotel</h2>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    <br/><br/>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </section>
        <section id="agenda" class="section">
  <h2>Agenda</h2>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </section>
          <section id="program" class="section">
  <h2>Program</h2>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  <br/><br/>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </section>
            <section id="winners" class="section">
  <h2>Winners</h2>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </section>
  <section id="travel" class="section">
  <h2>Travel</h2>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  <br/><br/>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </section>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are the links to other pages new HTML documents, or will you be changing the page content with JavaScript.  If it's JavaScript you simply add and remove a CSS class on the links. If it's a new HTML document every time, you need to set the active class either manually on each page or with the server-side code. I suppose you could do it with JS this way, but it would be much easier to do it in whatever server-side language you are using.

Comment: The index page holds the majority of the content but upon clicking on register the user is taken to several differnt pages that also have the navigation

Comment: So on those other pages is where you need to have them set which page has the currently active item in the navigation. Unless for some reason you don't have access to that code or language